# Is Geth safe to install?

Tags: go-ethereum, installation

I was wondering is Geth is safe to install, after I am unable to verify the PGP signatures of the developers.
I import the PGP keys into my keyring on my PC, but when I proceed to check the signature it gives the: "Bad Signature" (I am using Kleopatra on Windows). I tried importing the dev keys into my keyring, on my Android phone, using: "OpenKeyChain", but it gives me an error that there are no valid keys?
Could this be a phising website, and tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the binaries from the official site they should be valid. https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads.

If the verification fail I'll report the issue to their github repo. Try checking the files on linux (linux and mac usually have better support than windows on blockchain projects).